# how to set space Between Labels of xAxis

Tags: ios-charts

I got a problem of chart showing,you can see it from the picture.The old version of charts has api `spaceBetweenLabels` to set space Between Labels. I only find api `spaceMax` and `spaceMin` in the newest version. I try to use them  to set space between Labels, but that failed. I also tried to use api `labelWidth` to solve the problem, which failed too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIQia.png)

Answer (score 3):

Just set property `xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled` to `true`, e.g.
`myChart.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true`