# How to set space between x axis labels in IOS Charts?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I have been facing this problem for a long time. I wish to set equal space between the x-axis labels in my ios chart. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491480/how-to-set-space-between-labels-of-xaxis/43506317) solution and applied the code as `lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true`, but it didn't work out. Then I did set the value to be `false` then it gave me somewhat equal spacing but now my first and last x-axis label is being hidden in the chart. Please help me out with this solution.Here is the code for the line chart customization:

```
func setXaxis(){
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottomInside
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = chartcolor
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 6
    lineChartView.xAxis.xOffset = 10


}
func setYaxis(){
    lineChartView.leftAxis.labelPosition = YAxis.LabelPosition.insideChart
    lineChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = chartcolor
    lineChartView.leftAxis.gridColor = chartcolor
    lineChartView.leftAxis.labelCount = 5
    lineChartView.leftAxis.yOffset = 6
    lineChartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0)

}
func setChart(){
    lineChartView.noDataText = ""
    lineChartView.dragEnabled = false
    lineChartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
    lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    lineChartView.drawMarkers = true
    lineChartView.backgroundColor = bluecolor
    lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    lineChartView.legend.enabled = false
    lineChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false

}
```

These are my screenshots.

When : **lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true**

[image: first case]

When : **lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = false**

[image: second case]

Comment: Can you share your code? then I can run your code and see if I can find a solution

Comment: @DevB2F i have added the code