# Not able to refresh my JSON data through pull to refresh in tableview controller

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I am having the problem in refreshing my JSON data through pull to refresh.When I launch my application, then it is displaying the data but when I pull to refresh then it is not refreshing.
I have implemented the `Refresh Control` to refresh data. I am able to see the wheel icon of the pull to refresh, but it's not updating the JSON data.

Here is my code:

```
struct JSONData {
    let country: String
    let indicename: String
    let currPrice: String
    let chg: String
    let perChg: String

    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let country = dictionary["Country"] as? String,
            let indicename = dictionary["Indicename"] as? String,
            let currPrice = dictionary["CurrPrice"] as? String,
            let chg = dictionary["Chg"] as? String,
            let perChg = dictionary["perChg"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }
        self.country = country
        self.indicename = indicename
        self.currPrice = currPrice
        self.chg = chg
        self.perChg = perChg
    }
}

       class SouthAViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,IndicatorInfoProvider {

    var datas = [JSONData]()
        var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

          @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

        var arrowupimage : UIImage = UIImage(named : "arrowup")!
        var arrowdownimage : UIImage = UIImage(named : "arrowdown")!

        // I haven't shared the URL of parsing for security reasons

        let url=NSURL(string:"*******************************")
        let stringurl = "***************************"



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                tableview.refreshControl = refreshControl
            } else {
                tableview.addSubview(refreshControl)
            }

            self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

            self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SouthAViewController.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)


            navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
            self.downloadJsonWithURL()
            tableview.delegate = self
            tableview.dataSource = self
        }

        func refresh(){
            self.downloadJsonWithURL()

        }

        // downloading JSON data to display on this class

        func downloadJsonWithURL() {

             let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: stringurl)!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
              //  print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if let contdata = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [String:Any] {

                if let arrJSON = contdata["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    self.datas = arrJSON.flatMap(JSONData.init)

                        //Reload tableView and endRefreshing the refresh control
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }



        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return datas.count
        }

        //setting data on the table view cell

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "southacell", for: indexPath) as! southacell


        cell.Indicename?.text = datas[indexPath.row].indicename
        cell.Country?.text = datas[indexPath.row].country
        cell.CurrPrice?.text = datas[indexPath.row].currPrice


            return cell
        }

    }
```

json sample :

```
{  "data":[  
      {  
         "Country":"China",
         "Indicename":"SZSE COMPONENT INDEX",
         "date":"2017-06-23 14:53:57",
         "zone":"GMT+8",
         "CurrPrice":"10355.3",
         "Chg":"90.07",
         "PerChg":"0.88",
         "prev_close":"10265.2"
      },
      {  
         "Country":"China",
         "Indicename":"Shanghai Composite",
         "date":"2017-06-23 14:52:54",
         "zone":"GMT+8",
         "CurrPrice":"3155.9",
         "Chg":"8.44",
         "PerChg":"0.27",
         "prev_close":"3147.45"
      }
]
}
```

Comment: the data is returned from server on refresh time

Comment: I dont think, if it would have happened then it would have been updated also.

Comment: The first time when i run my application then the data is being loaded in my table view cell

Comment: chekc once ....

Comment: should i print the value in my refresh function and them check ??

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Is it loading data in tableView when you load the screen ? If yes edit your question with current code that you are trying also put once break point and check reload data in completion block is executing or not

Comment: @NiravD I have updated the code, am I loading the data correctly in table view cell ,please check it sir

Comment: @NiravD No I am not getting any data right now through the above code when I am loading my app. Now no data is being displayed. and while putting the breakpoint I saw that the `datas` array is not getting any value from json

Comment: @NiravD i have added the json sample

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal The issue is to small, change single line in `init` of JSONData `let perChg = dictionary["PerChg"] as? String else {` for key `PerChg` `P` is capital currently it is in lowercase make it capital and you all good to go.

Comment: @NiravD ok sir i did it . But what about the refresh .It is stiill not working

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Is refresh control showing when you refresh the tableView ? Also put break point inside `refresh` and check it is getting called or not ?

Comment: @NiravD yes sir refresh function is being called.But it is not refreshing the data

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Check this line `self.datas = arrJSON.flatMap(JSONData.init)` is executing when you refresh the tableView put break point and check it. if it is executing that means you are getting the same data so tableView is showing the same result.

Comment: @NiravD Sir its done. Now it's refresing the data

Comment: @NiravD thanks a lot, sir. You helped me a lot with this. May I get your email id to get in contact in case of any problem. I am just a beginner right now in IOS

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal You can ping me here on this question, with your new question link If I have solution will post on you question.

Comment: @NiravD great sir. Thanks :)

Comment: @NiravD I posted a question yesterday regarding the ios charts .Please do have a look at it and provide any solution if u have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700493/how-to-set-space-between-x-axis-labels-in-ios-charts

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal I have already seen this question, I haven't work with charts so don't have any solution for tha.

Comment: @NiravD Okk Sir !

Comment: @NiravD Sir I am facing a problem in setting the dynamic resizing of table view cell. I tried this  in my `viewDidLoad()` method : `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120` and in my storyboard also I have set the custom row height as 120, but it's not working.It is in fact now displaying a bigger cell height than before .What may be the reason? Should I post a question for it or you have an answer?

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal The issue may related to constraints add new question with your cell's content with its constraints

Comment: @NiravD how should i show you the constraints. I have added them in the storyboard

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Actually currently I'm busy with some task so will not able to help you now, so better if you add new question

Comment: @NiravD okk sir . I . will send you the link over here.Please do have a look when u get time

Comment: @NiravD sir whenever you get time.please check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753952/not-able-to-set-the-dynamic-height-of-table-view-cell

Comment: @NiravD Sir i am in a problem ,sir now my whole project seems to be absurdly aligned , i was going through a tutorial  and i disable Auto Layout in  File inspector and now my whole project is messed up i think , is there any solution to get things back done in the same layout or i have to assign the constraint again ?

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Don't get you.

Comment: @NiravD leave it sir , the main issue is i am not able to set the constraints for all the labels and other content of my table view cell for setting it to have dynamic height

Comment: I want to set the dynamic height so the main issue is my contraints . Thats why  i am having trouble, it's a bit confusing

Comment: @NiravD I solved the issue sir :)

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Thats great that you made it :)

Comment: @NiravD Sir how do we convert a particular date into UTC. I used the following code:   
       `let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
        formatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter1.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let parsed = formatter1.date(from: self.datas[0].date)`
It is showing me the following result : 2017-06-27 18:05:01 +0000
Is it the correct time being displayed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147781/discussion-between-nirav-d-and-samarth-kejriwal).

Comment: @NiravD Sir I have made my whole view with all the labels and images  done , but now I want to make the whole  view scrollable  by adding a scroll view ,is it possible to add the scroll view at the bottom of the whole view without disturbing the layouts of the labels and images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Data(contentsOf:)` to retrieve data from `URL` what you need to use is `URLSession` with `datatask` to retrieve data from `URL` after that you need to reload the `tableView` and ending animation of `RefreshControl` inside the completion block of `datatask(with:)`. Also instead of handling multiple array what you need to do is create one array of custom `class` or `struct`

```
struct Data {
    var country: String
    var indicename: String
    var currPrice: String
    var chg: String
    var perChg: String

    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let country = dictionary["Country"] as? String,
              let indicename = dictionary["Indicename"] as? String,
              let currPrice = dictionary["CurrPrice"] as? String,
              let chg = dictionary["Chg"] as? String,
              let perChg = dictionary["PerChg"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        self.country = country
        self.indicename = indicename
        self.currPrice = currPrice
        self.chg = chg
        self.perChg = perChg
    }
}
```

Now declare simply one array of type `[Data]` and use this will your `tableView` methods.

```
var datas = [Data]()
```

Now simply use this single array to store all the data and display data in `tableView`.

```
func refresh(){
    self.downloadJsonWithURL()
}

func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if let contdata = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [String:Any] {
            if let arrJSON = contdata["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                self.datas = arrJSON.flatMap(Data.init)
                //Reload tableView and endRefreshing the refresh control 
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

//tableView methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data.count
}

//setting data on the table view cell

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "southacell", for: indexPath) as! southacell


    let curpricefloat : Double = Double(datas[indexPath.row].currPrice)!
    let Chgfloat : Double = Double(datas[indexPath.row].chg)!
    let perchgfloat : Double = Double(datas[indexPath.row].perChg)!

    cell.Indicename?.text = datas[indexPath.row].indicename
    cell.Indicename.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 19.0)
    cell.Country?.text = datas[indexPath.row].country

    cell.PerChg?.text = "(" + String(format: "%.2f", perchgfloat) + "%)"
    cell.CurrPrice?.text = String(format: "%.2f", curpricefloat)
    cell.Chg?.text = String(format: "%.2f", Chgfloat)

    if Float((cell.Chg?.text)!)! < 0 {

        datas[indexPath.row].chg = datas[indexPath.row].chg.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        datas[indexPath.row].perChg = datas[indexPath.row].perChg.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")

        cell.PerChg?.text = "(" + datas[indexPath.row].perChg + "%)"
        cell.Chg?.text = datas[indexPath.row].chg

        cell.Chg?.textColor = UIColor.red
        cell.PerChg?.textColor = UIColor.red
        cell.arrow?.image = UIImage(named : "arrowdown")

    } else
    {
        cell.Chg?.textColor = UIColor.green
        cell.PerChg?.textColor = UIColor.green
        cell.arrow?.image = UIImage(named : "arrowup")
    }

    if cell.Country!.text! == "Argentina"{
        cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "argentina")
    }
    else if cell.Country!.text! == "Brazil"{
        cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "brazil")
    }
    else if cell.Country!.text! == "Peru"{
        cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "peru")
    }
    else{
        cell.countryFlag?.image = UIImage(named : "unknown")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Try like edited answer and make some struct or class

Comment: It is still not working sir .Not refreshing the data

Comment: help needed regarding the ios deployment version

Comment: I wanted some help regarding the scroll view in ios

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal Please add that as a new question, send me link if I have solution will post for you

Comment: I solved it myself and in future if any query then i will share the link with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // MARK: Refresh control
    updateData.backgroundColor = .black
    updateData.tintColor = .white
    updateData.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Updating Tap 
List...", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 
255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
    updateData.addTarget(self, action: 
#selector(ViewController.loadNewData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    tapListTableView.addSubview(updateData)
    tapListTableView.sendSubview(toBack: updateData)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```