# Not able to set the dynamic height of table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I am having the problem in setting the dynamic height for my table view cell.I have used the following code to set it, but it's not working in fact now the cell height has even increased.

See this the code I have added in my project:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        print(tableview.rowHeight)
        tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 120

}
```

This the screenshot for the constraints of the table view cell contents:
[image: Constraints for my content view of the table view cell]

Please have a look at the constraints as well. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: May it will help you https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: @DSDharma I have followed this tutorial as well but didn't helped me out

Comment: @DSDharma will you please check out the constraints once, may be there must be a problem

Comment: Make sure height constant should be greater then equal instead of constant

Comment: @DSDharma in which case you are talking, please elaborate

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal which label should have dynamic height.? indices name right..?

Comment: @Gokul no i want that the whole table view cell should have a dynamic height

Comment: Your constraint probably is wrong, you have to make sure the cell can determine your cell height by pinning the labels to top and bottom, if error show, change their priority

Comment: @Tj3n you mean to say that i have to set the bottom and top space for each label wrt to the cell

Comment: not to the cell, but to each other to form a height for the cell , like if label1 on top of label2, add constraint like cell top-label1-label2-cellbottom, that will form a height for the cell to auto calculate

Comment: ok so you mean to say that i have to define the top bottom contraints relative to each other label

Comment: @Tj3n please help me out with the constraints . i am not getting it right man .i am new to ios development

Comment: If it show error (because lines = 0), then you have to select 1 of the 2 label, change their content hugging and resistance priority, the error will gone, its also mentioned in the tutorial on first comment

Comment: Pin all the labels/other components to top and bottom too and set height for each as height >= somevalue. Also change lines of label to 0.

Comment: trying the things

Comment: I am not able to set the constraimts properly ..really messed up :(

Comment: @Gokul i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If u have done everything correct and still u r unable the get desired output means the issue will be with constraints.
- I have made a simple constraint layout, use this skeleton as reference and re-constraint your cell.
  [image]
- Add (W:20, H:20) to [img].
- Make sure you have set number of lines to 0, and all other automatic dimension stuff's.
- IB Constraint Screenshot.

[image]

## OutPut:

[image]

Comment: you havent defined the top and leading constraints ..should i define them as well ?

Comment: just keep it as reference.. the image may have missed some constraint.. try to follow the same

Comment: wait i am setting the constraints and then i will send u the screen shot .and then check

Comment: the problem is that my indicesname label is covering the whole width when the indices name is too long and so my curr price item is getting hidden,should i set a desired height for it ?

Comment: if width of indices name is your problm.. add a `Horizontal constraint` between `indices` and `price`. change it's relation to `>=` and constant to 10

Comment: i had set the width of the indices name as proportional to 0.7 of the width of the content view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147607/discussion-between-gokul-and-samarth-kejriwal).

Comment: actually when i was setting the proportional height for my image view in the table view cell then my table view cell height was abruplty expanded, is there any other way to handle this . I am having this problem while setting a proptional height for image view , if i set a proportional width to my image view along with an aspect ration then i dont ge this problem

Comment: hi, continue this discussion in chat

Comment: help needed regarding ios deployment version

Comment: Hi Gokul, needed some help, message me when you are free

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`. It's a method in the UITableViewDelegate and you can use it to return a specific height for the rows you want.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

This link may help: 
[Dynamic tableViewCell height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556322/dynamic-tableviewcell-height)

Comment: I know this is a method, but I have to set a dynamic height, i.e. I want to change the height of each row according to my changing content in the table view cell

Comment: There's likely something wrong with your constraints. Check to see that there are no errors, i.e. any red lines.

Comment: @MihitThanekar there isn't any red lines i have already checked it

Comment: Great so try the latter link on my post. Summary: 1. Set constraints. You did that. 2. Set lines on the label to 0. 3. Implement the heightForRow and estimatedHeightForRow and return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in both. Did that help? Let us know.

Comment: Should i set each label lines as 0 ?

Comment: Yup. That's what the other forum post said. Try it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147589/discussion-between-mihir-thanekar-and-samarth-kejriwal).